# Cheerio npm : obtaining data from script returns white space ~ node.js

Tags: node.js, cheerio

```
const $ = cheerio.load(response)
console.log($('script type="text/javascript"').text())
```

Response contains page's source

Want to obtain data from the script section as shown above, but returns white space.

Can someone give me a brief overview `with the answer to solve this issue` on how to format the `$(x x)` in such scenarios, because I'm always struggling with them?

Answer (score 0):

Your mean is find tag script has attribute `type` is `text/javascript` ?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> something </script>
```

Try this:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(response)
console.log($('script[type="text/javascript"]').html())
```